# Ждать кого, чего? или кого, что?

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Проясните, пожалуйста, какой падеж в каком случае употребляется с глаголом "ждать". Я так понимаю, что и родительный и винительный.
Предложение таково:

> Письма ждут (поезда,корабли,человек – все это пока в им.падеже), чтобы разлететься по свету.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего эта тема изложена на сайте "Культура письменной речи", но етая культура не позволяет себя копировать...

Даю нужный фрагмент скриншотом и ссылочку на весь текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[источник](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.21)**